Need help understanding this tangent line problem
The problem is, “If the line tangent to the graph of $f$ at $(1, 7)$ goes through $(2, 3)$, which of the following must be true?
A. $f’(1) = \frac{1}{4}$
B. $f’(2) = -\frac{1}{4}$
C. $f(2) = 3$
D. $f’(1) = -4$
E. $f’(2) = -4$
So far I used the formula slope formula on the two points to get the slop. Since the slope is equal to the derivative I can kind of get my answer D. However, I’m not sure why it couldn’t also be E. How do I know $f’(2) = -4$ isn’t also true. I also am not sure how to prove C. to be false as well. Any help understanding this question is greatly appreciated.

"I also am not sure how to prove c to be false as well." There's no need to: (c) needn't be false, and the question asks for the option that MUST be true. $\quad$ "I’m not sure why it couldn’t also be E." What do you reckon is the difference between assertions D and E?

They are asking which must be true, not which can be true.

Choice E isn’t necessarily true, because even though the tangent line with slope $-4$ passes through $(2,3)$, we don’t know if the line is actually tangent to the function at $(2,3)$, so we don’t know the slope of $f$ at $x=2$. We only know that the line is tangent to the function at $(1,7)$.

The question asks what must be true. Your reasoning why f'(1) = 7 is correct.
You don't need to prove that other statements are false. You only need to know that they don't have to be true.

Using the slope formula $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$, we calculate the slope of the tangent line as $-4$. Since the slope of the tangent line at $x=1$ is the derivative at that point, we have $$f'(1)=-4$$
Hence D. is true.

Option A. is wrong as this contradicts the slope calculation of $f'(1)=-4$.
Option B. is wrong as there is no information given about the slope of the function at $x=2$. We know the line passes through $(2,3)$ but this option suggests a specific value for the derivative which we cannot confirm from the given information.
Option C. if this is $f(2)=3$, then it is obviously true. I assume that you made a typo as all other options contain derivatives - so in that case, I cite the same reasoning as rejecting option B.
Option E. is wrong for same reasons as B. and potentially C.
